# Extension Attributes is not working

Tags: magento2.2, extension-attributes

I have added one field i.e. **checksum** alongwith coupon code on payment page. Now I want to get and set checksum field.

I tried,

**etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
          <extension_attributes for="Magento\GiftCardAccount\Api\Data\GiftCardInterface">
          <attribute code="checksum" type="Test\GiftCard\Api\Data\GiftCardInterface" />
          </extension_attributes>
    </config>
```

**Test\GiftCard\Api\Data\GiftCardInterface**

```
<?php

namespace Test\GiftCard\Api\Data;

interface GiftCardInterface
{
     public function getChecksum();    
     public function setChecksum($checksum);
}
```

But I am getting error -

```
      Property \"Checksum\" does not have accessor method \"getChecksum\" in class \"Magento\\GiftCardAccount\\Api\\Data\\GiftCardAccountInterface\".
```

Answer (score -1):

At, `Test\GiftCard\Api\Data\GiftCardInterface` interface

**`getChecksum(),setChecksum()`** should have method singnature means it

**Like:**

```
<?php

namespace Test\GiftCard\Api\Data;

interface GiftCardInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */ 
     public function getChecksum();   

    /**
     *
     * @param string $checksum
     * @return $this
     */ 
     public function setChecksum($checksum);
}
```

Here return type of getter method getChecksum is string because of  field type is **varchar**.

**After these changes, you need run di compile command properly.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still I am getting same error

Comment: try  to add ACL resource `<resources>
                <resource ref="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"/>
            </resources>` See  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Comment: ok, i will try through ACL resource